# Where can I find a list of snow fall recording stations in my zip code?

Tags: meteorology, open-data, snow, database, cryosphere

Where can I find the locations on snow fall recording stations in a particular United States county or zip code? Is there a way that I can find an hour by hour recent history of snow fall? Hour by hour for the last 7 days would be interesting but even the last 24 hours would be very helpful. I need to to know where and when to dispatch crews to remove snow from office and apartment buildings, often in the middle of the night when I don't have eyes on the ground.

I may have to resort to installing web cams so I can personally review the conditions remotely.  The lake level stations are so accurate and easily accessible, I thought they might have sometime for precipitation as well.

I would prefer reports in inches of precipitation rather than inches of snow, but either would work. I find the former to be more accurate for my needs. It's the amount of water that needs to me moved that matters, no matter if it is densely packed or loosely packed.

Comment: please update your question,where do you live? i think we need some basic information to answer this.

Comment: The mention of zip codes indicates US, yes?

Comment: if you get precipitation and multiply it by the rain-snow ratio, it's about 12.

Comment: I apologize for making an assumption. thank u2 the people that responded. The question is USA centric;I should have stated that. The US Geologic Survey has a great website where they show lake levels, river levels, river flows etc in near real time Unmanned sensors are located everywhere there is one a block from my home powered by a solar panel connected to a wireless modem. Everything is automated, accurate and almost real time. They also have a way of measuring the remaining snow pack (on the ground) but that is mostly in western states. I was hoping NOAA had something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Were to find hourly data will depend on your location, as you will probably need to access the national weather network of the country of your interest. Global climatic databases usually record data on daily basis. Like the [Global Historical Climate Network](http://Global%20Historical%20Climate%20Network), you can search for all the station in that network and query snowfall data in the [KNMI Climate Explorer](https://climexp.knmi.nl/selectdailyseries.cgi?id=someone@somewhere). This is a example query of all the stations between 50 and 51° North and 120 and 122° West (to convert ZIP codes to coordinates you can use [geocoder](https://geocoder.ca/) or other similar services):

[image]

It returns 39 stations, each one with a record like this:

[image]

And you can also download the raw data.

Comment: Since this web site appears to cover Canada, I look forward to trying some US lat/lons to see if it also covers the US. I will be looking for data that is more granular than the graphs show. I look forward to seeing what is available, Every night local media reports how much snow fell on this day in history. Someone must keep the records and I look forward to who has them. Thank you.